# Get record from SQL Server from two tables with optimized code

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables - one is `Product` and the other is `Productimage`. In product image table, more than one image can exist of every product. Every image set ISDEAULT 1 or 0. Now I want every product from product table whose all image's ISDEAULT is 0.

I wrote this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT(pd.ProductId) 
FROM Product pd
INNER JOIN ProductImage img ON img.ProductId =  pd.ProductId
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT pdi.ProductId 
    FROM ProductImage pdi 
    WHERE pdi.IsDefault = 1 
    AND pdi.ProductId = pd.ProductId
)
```

It works correctly but my senior told me to use another approach.

Please give me optimized query

Comment: I think the `INNER JOIN` is not neccesary.

Comment: Side notes: `DISTINCT` is not a function, you don't need `()` as it works on the whole resultset. For `NOT EXISTS` it makes no difference what you select, you may as well do `SELECT 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation to check for `IsDefault = 1`

This means you are only querying the `ProductImage` table once

```sql
SELECT  pd.ProductId
FROM Product pd
JOIN ProductImage img ON img.ProductId =  pd.ProductId
GROUP BY
  pd.ProductId
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN img.IsDefault = 1 THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

If you don't care if it has *any* `ProductImage` then you can just do

```sql
SELECT  pd.ProductId
FROM Product pd
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM ProductImage img
    WHERE img.ProductId =  pd.ProductId
    AND img.IsDefault = 1);
```

Comment: What problem using where statement

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT IMG.PRODUCTID
FROM ProductImage AS img
GROUP BY IMG.PRODUCTID
HAVING MIN(ISDEAULT )=0 AND MAX(ISDEAULT)=0
```

Could you please try something like this

Answer (score 0):

Another way :

```
SELECT DISTINCT pd.ProductId
FROM   Product AS pd
       INNER JOIN ProductImage AS img 
          ON img.ProductId =  pd.ProductId
       LEFT OUTER JOIN ProductImage AS pdi 
          ON pdi.IsDefault = 1 
             AND pdi.ProductId = pd.ProductId
WHERE  pdi.ProductId  IS NULL
```

Another way (2)

```
SELECT pd.ProductId 
FROM   Product pd
       INNER JOIN ProductImage img ON img.ProductId =  pd.ProductId
EXCEPT
SELECT pd.ProductId 
FROM   Product pd
       INNER JOIN ProductImage img ON img.ProductId =  pd.ProductId
WHERE pdi.IsDefault = 1
```

Also a simplification can be :

```
SELECT DISTINCT pd.ProductId
FROM ProductImage AS pi
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM ProductImage img
    WHERE img.ProductId =  pi.ProductId
    AND img.IsDefault = 1);
```

Also :

```
SELECT ProductId
FROM   Product
EXCEPT
SELECT ProductId
FROM   ProductImage 
WHERE  IsDefault = 1
GROUP  BY ProductId
HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
```

One more

```
SELECT img.ProductId
FROM ProductImage  AS img
GROUP BY img.ProductId
HAVING  MAX(CAST(IsDefault AS SMALLINT))=0;
```